# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

Am trying to create a search option in Postpage with some location data. But it gives the error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" . Here am adding those codes . The page file and corresponding service class already declared in app.module.ts file.

### post.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Back</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
<ion-content padding text-center>
   <ion-title>Search Restaurunt Location</ion-title>
      <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"   (ionInput)="setFilteredItems()"></ion-searchbar>

      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let data of locationdata">
            {{data.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

### post.service.ts

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Data

{
    locationdata:any;
constructor()
{
    this.locationdata=[
        { "name":"EKM"},
        {"name":"CBD"},
        { "name":"KLM"},
        { "name":"KTR"},
        { "name":"CDL"},

    ];
}
    filteritems(searchTerm)
    {
        return this.locationdata.filter((item) => {
            return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(item.searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        });  
    }
}
```

### Post.ts

```
import { Component  ,ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Data}from './post.service'
declare var google :any;

/**
 * Generated class for the PostPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-post',
  templateUrl: 'post.html',
})
export class PostPage {
@ViewChild('map')mapref : ElementRef;
map:any;
searchTerm:any;
locationdata:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams , public data :Data) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // this.showmap();
    this.setFilteredItems();
  }

setFilteredItems()
{
  this.locationdata= this.data.filteritems(this.searchTerm)
}

}
```

### Post.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PostPage } from './post';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PostPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(PostPage),
  ],
})
export class PostPageModule {}
```

Comment: searchterm is not from item object so remove item before search term

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `item.name` is not undefined and here I think `searchterm` not available in `item` object it should be from the parameter variable of filteritems function.

```
filteritems(searchTerm)
    {
        return this.locationdata.filter((item) => {
              if(item.name && searchTerm) {
                return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
              }
        });  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove item parameter from your includes method.

```
    filteritems(searchTerm:string)
    {
         if(searchTerm){        
 return this.locationdata.filter((item) => {
                        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
                    }); 
                     }
    }
```

**item.searchTerm.toLowerCase()** means you are trying to access the property **searchTerm** of the **item** object( { "name":"EKM"}) and hence it is undefined and then toLowerCase() of undefined as the error.